# c# y access obtener el valor mayor de una columna

Tags: c#

buen día estoy tratando de obtener el ultimo registro ingresado en una tabla, ya hay varios clientes ingresado sin embargo en la ejecución cuando intento darle el valor leído a una variable me muestra un error "No hay ningun dato disponible para la fila o columna"

```
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection probar = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\base_datos_red.accdb; Persist Security Info=false");
            probar.Open();
            OleDbCommand c = new OleDbCommand("select max(clave) from clientes", probar);
            OleDbDataReader a = c.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show(a.GetString(0));
            probar.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberias hacer para poder obtener 1 o más valores desde una consulta es recorrer el `reader` de tu consulta. En cuanto a mejorar un poco el codigo los `using` puedes definirlos

```
string connString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\base_datos_red.accdb; Persist Security Info=false";

string consulta = "select max(clave) from clientes";

using (OleDbConnection probar = new OleDbConnection(connString))
using (OleDbCommand c = new OleDbCommand(consulta, probar))
{
    try
    {
        probar.Open();
        OleDbCommand c = new OleDbCommand("select max(clave) from clientes", probar);
        OleDbDataReader a = c.ExecuteReader();
        while(a.Read()){
           //Leer el DataReader y obtener el/los campos del registro
           MessageBox.Show(a[0].ToString());
        }
        a.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias me ha funcionado...

Comment: De nada, te deje una recomendación para el `catch` para que muestres correctamente el error

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunos problemas básicos:

- Después de ejecutar `c.ExecuteReader()`, debes ejecutar `a.Read()` una vez antes de usar `a.GetString()` para poder leer el resultado.
- El parámetro que usas para `a.GetString(-1)` es incorrecto. Debería ser `0`: `a.GetString(0)`

**Sugerencias adicionales:**

- Ya que tu consulta garantiza que va a devolver una sola fila y un solo valor, usa `a.ExecuteScalar()` mas bien.
- `""+ex` es un poco raro. `ex.ToString()` me parece mejor.
- No te olvides de cerrar el `OleDbDataReader`
- Para evitar que se te pase cerrar los objetos en caso de excepciones, acostúmbrate a usar bloques `using`.

**Código sugerido:**

```
try
{
    string resultado = null;
    using (OleDbConnection probar = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\base_datos_red.accdb; Persist Security Info=false"))
    {
        probar.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand c = new OleDbCommand("select max(clave) from clientes", probar))
        {
            resultado = (string)c.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    // Mostrar el resultado después de cerrar la conexión
    // es mejor para evitar guardar la conexión abierta innecesariamente
    MessageBox.Show(resultado);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```